# Advent of Code 2016: Day 1 "No Time for a Taxicab"

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

Here I'm talking about Part 2 of the [puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/1), where we need to find "How many blocks away is the first location you visit twice?".

At first I solved it as everybody else using a set of all visited points.
Peter Norvig employed that approach, you can check his solution [on GitHub](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/ipynb/Advent%20of%20Code.ipynb).

My code was not that elegant, but Peter's notebook reminded me of existence of [`complex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) type, so I modified my function and ended up here:

```
def solve_set(instructions):
    direction, loc, visited = 1j, 0, {0}
    for i in instructions.split(', '):
        direction *= {'R': -1j, 'L': 1j}[i[0]]
        for _ in range(int(i[1:])):
            loc += direction
            if loc in visited:
                return abs(loc.real) + abs(loc.imag)
            visited.add(loc)
```

Now let's try to optimize it.

The puzzle uses [Taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry),
and if we assume that all instructions have a positive number of steps (greater than zero),
we can split segments into two subsets, `parallel` and `orthogonal`,
and for each new segment check only `orthogonal` segments for an intersection.
No matter what, on a new instruction (i.e. new segment) those two sets interchange,
so `parallel` segments become `orthogonal` and `orthogonal` become `parallel`.
To update subsets (represented as lists) we use `insort` function from `bisect` module
which inserts an element into a list keeping it sorted.
Then we get a list of `candidates` from `orthogonal` set of segments using `bisect` function
and iterate over it in the `direction` of current segment to get the first intersection:

```
from bisect import bisect, insort

def solve_bisect(instructions):
    N, E, S = 1j, 1, -1j
    direction, cur, prev, prev_s = N, 0, 0, None
    parallel, orthogonal = [], []  # segments
    for i in instructions.split(', '):
        direction *= {'R': -1j, 'L': 1j}[i[0]]
        cur += direction * int(i[1:])
        if direction in (N, S): s = prev.real, prev.imag, cur.imag
        else:                   s = prev.imag, prev.real, cur.real
        insort(parallel, s)
        candidates = orthogonal[bisect(orthogonal, s[1:2]) : bisect(orthogonal, s[2:])]
        for c in candidates if direction in (N, E) else candidates[::-1]:
            if prev_s != c and (c[1] <= s[0] <= c[2] or c[2] <= s[0] <= c[1]):
                return abs(s[0]) + abs(c[0])
        prev, prev_s, parallel, orthogonal = cur, s, orthogonal, parallel
```

Now we need to generate a large input for comparison:

```
from random import choice, randrange
instructions = ', '.join(f'{choice("LR")}{randrange(1, 1000000)}' for _ in range(100000))
```

I don't know what you will end up with, but I get these results:

```
In [15]: %timeit solve_bisect(instructions)
5.91 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit solve_set(instructions)
465 ms ± 8.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So in this case `solve_bisect` is roughly 100x times faster than the naive approach.

But I'd like to know if there's an even better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 5 → 3.

Comment: @200_success, I've posted an answer below. Gareth's answer helped me to find a bug and fix it. I suppose I have to accept it and move my answer to a new question if I want to get feedback on the updated version of code, is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Before starting to make timing comparisons, it's important to check that the optimized code is correct. It's no good being a hundred times faster if you get the wrong answer! So let's look at the results of the two functions on a simple test case:

```
>>> instructions = 'L1, L1, L1, L1, R1, R1, R1, R1'
>>> solve_set(instructions)
0.0
>>> solve_bisect(instructions)
1.0
```

Oops.

Comment: Gareth, thanks for your time! There was a bug in `solve_bisect`. I've updated my post, hopefully it's correct now (see Update section). I can't agree with your last statement: just run something like `solve_set('R100000000')`. The "only extra work" takes a lot of resources actually :)

Comment: It still doesn't matter if the result you get is wrong :) What Gareth tried to tell you is: "_Focus first on correctness, then speed_"

Comment: @MrGrj, yeah, I didn't pay enough attention to correctness the first time. `solve_bisect_v2` is (hopefully) correct. And I still want to hear some feedback on it :)

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the problem. I've edited my answer to remove the incorrect claim.

Answer (score 2):

Gareth pointed out that `solve_bisect` is not correct.

There is obviously a bug and here's a fixed version of the function:

```
def solve_bisect_v2(instructions):
    N, E, S = 1j, 1, -1j
    _inf, inf = float('-inf'), float('inf')
    direction, pos, prev_pos, prev_segment = N, 0, 0, None
    parallel, orthogonal = [], []  # segments
    for i in instructions.split(', '):
        direction *= {'R': -1j, 'L': 1j}[i[0]]
        pos += direction * int(i[1:])
        #                                  "Level"        start-end
        if direction in (N, S): segment = (prev_pos.real, *sorted([prev_pos.imag, pos.imag]))
        else:                   segment = (prev_pos.imag, *sorted([prev_pos.real, pos.real]))
        if orthogonal and segment[0] == 0 and segment[1] <= 0 <= segment[2]:
            return 0
        insort(parallel, segment)
        start = bisect_left (orthogonal, (segment[1], _inf))
        end   = bisect_right(orthogonal, (segment[2],  inf))
        candidates = orthogonal[start:end]
        for c in candidates if direction in (N, E) else candidates[::-1]:
            if prev_segment != c and c[1] <= segment[0] <= c[2]:
                return abs(segment[0]) + abs(c[0])
        prev_pos, prev_segment, parallel, orthogonal = pos, segment, orthogonal, parallel
```

I've changed some variable names to make it more readable.

`solve_bisect_v2` passes next tests:

```
cases = [
    ('R1', None),
    ('L1, L1, L1, L1', 0),
    ('R1, R1, R2, R1, R1', 0),
    ('R8, R4, R4, R8', 4),
]

for instructions, answer in cases:
    assert solve_bisect_v2(instructions) == answer
```

I've also run the next loop for a couple of minutes and it didn't stop on its own:

```
while True:
    instructions = ', '.join(f'{choice("LR")}{randrange(1, 1000000)}' for _ in range(100000))
    assert solve_set(instructions) == solve_bisect_v2(instructions)
```

The logic hasn't really changed. I've fixed `candidates` calculation and added a check for segments running through `(0, 0)` that are colinear to the first segment (`cases[2]` checks that).